# Testing Promises in Mocha and Chai

Tags: javascript, express, promise, mocha.js, chai

```
export class YoutubeService {
  getTrendingVideos(country) {
    var params = {
      part: 'snippet',
      chart: 'mostPopular',
      regionCode: country, // should be replaced with country code from countryList
      maxResults: '24',
      key: config.youtubeApi.key
    };
    let result = [];
    let promises = [];
    return axios.get('/', {params}).then(function(res){
      result = res.data.items;
      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          result[i] = {
              id: result[i].id,
              title: result[i].snippet.title,
              thumbnail: result[i].snippet.thumbnails.high.url,
              publishedAt: moment(result[i].snippet.publishedAt).fromNow()
          };
          promises.push(YoutubeService.getVideoDetails(result[i]));
      }
      return Promise.all(promises);
    });
  }

  static getVideoDetails(video) {
    let params = {
      part: 'statistics',
      id: video.id,
      key: config.youtubeApi.key
    };

    return axios.get('/', {params}).then(function(res) {
      let result = res.data;
      video.viewCount = result['items'][0].statistics.viewCount;
      video.likeCount = result['items'][0].statistics.likeCount;
      return video;
    });
  }
}
```

I am new to the use of mocha and chai for testing, especially promises. How can I test these two functions using chai assertions.
How should I unit test these two functions
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Personally first I'd pull out code that isn't directly related to the class (e.g., `params` is always the same except for a single property), refactor more (e.g., creating video detail result request props can stand alone), use things like `map`, build an array of request props, test the prop creator and the map function, *then* make the promises, etc. Beyond that, I'm pretty sure I've seen multiple tutorials on testing promisified code--but I think it would be helpful if you mentioned what the *specific* issue you're having is.

Answer (score 0):

You would send a function into `it`, and the function would receive a `done` function to call after you finish resolving.

```
it('does resolve later', function(done) {
    asyncCall().then(()=>{ done(); }
})


it('does resolve later', async function(done) {
    await asyncCall()
    done()
})
```

You can also return a promise.

```
it('does resolve later', function () {
    return asyncCall()
})
```

Comment: what will be my asyncCall() here? getTrendingVideos or getVideoDetails()?

Comment: getVideoDetails.  It calls getTrendingVideos and waits for that to complete.

Comment: BTW you can also return promises in Mocha instead of calling done()

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Chai as Promised](http://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/) library which provides the chainable `eventually` that helps remove some boilerplate for expecting async resolution:

```
describe('YoutubeService.getTrendingVideos', function() {
  it('should resolve to expectedResult', function() {
    const params = '';
    const expectedResult = [];
    return getTrendingVideos(params).should.eventually.equal(expectedResult);
  });
});
```